# Вход ВК apache.http.client

Tags: apache, http, java, httpclient

Здравствуйте.
Нашёл на [хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/post/144813/) такой код для получения токена ВК для работы с API.Но он уже устарел на текущий момент,подскажите как его можно обновить до текущей версии библиотеки apache.http.client или подскажите какой версии нужно скачать эту библиотеку чтобы всё работало.

```
public static void getAPIToken() throws Exception {
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    // Делаем первый запрос
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://oauth.vk.com/authorize?"
            + "client_id=" + client_id
            + "&scope=" + scope
            + "&redirect_uri=" + redirect_uri
            + "&display=" + display
            + "&response_type=" + response_type);
    HttpResponse response;
    response = httpClient.execute(post);
    post.abort();
    //Получаем редирект
    String HeaderLocation = response.getFirstHeader("location").getValue();
    URI RedirectUri = new URI(HeaderLocation);
    //Для запроса авторизации необходимо два параметра полученных в первом запросе
    //ip_h и to_h
    String ip_h = RedirectUri.getQuery().split("&")[2].split("=")[1];
    String to_h = RedirectUri.getQuery().split("&")[4].split("=")[1];
    // Делаем запрос авторизации
    post = new HttpPost("https://login.vk.com/?act=login&soft=1"
            + "&q=1"
            + "&ip_h=" + ip_h
            + "&from_host=oauth.vk.com"
            + "&to=" + to_h
            + "&expire=0"
            + "&email=" + email
            + "&pass=" + pass);
    response = httpClient.execute(post);
    post.abort();
    // Получили редирект на подтверждение требований приложения
    HeaderLocation = response.getFirstHeader("location").getValue();
    post = new HttpPost(HeaderLocation);
    // Проходим по нему
    response = httpClient.execute(post);
    post.abort();
    // Теперь последний редирект на получение токена
    HeaderLocation = response.getFirstHeader("location").getValue();
    // Проходим по нему
    post = new HttpPost(HeaderLocation);
    response = httpClient.execute(post);
    post.abort();
    // Теперь в след редиректе необходимый токен
    HeaderLocation = response.getFirstHeader("location").getValue();
    // Просто спарсим его сплитами
    access_token = HeaderLocation.split("#")[1].split("&")[0].split("=")[1];
}
```

Лог компиляции:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/HttpRequest
at olike.bot.OlikeBot.getAPIToken(OlikeBot.java:128)
at olike.bot.OlikeBot.main(OlikeBot.java:44)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.HttpRequest
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 2 more
    Java Result: 1
```

Comment: Что конкретно у вас не получается? Вы уверены, что устарела версия HttpClient, а не код работы с VK API?

Comment: http://i66.fastpic.ru/big/2014/0727/e1/abdaa1b71a9a27cb18bf58e2301896e1.jpg

Забыл добавить,да и нельзя мне нормально заливать картинки.

Comment: @LowSkiII Картинка не нужна вовсе. Можно приложить лог компиляции. Отредактируйте вопрос дополнив его необходимой информацией. За одно приведите ссылку на пост, с которого вы взяли код.

Comment: Отредактировал как надо.

Comment: вк упал api сейчас не работает

Comment: Ошибка не связана с тем,что вк лежит.

Comment: @LowSkiII, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` - Не подключена библиотека. Добавьте в `ClassPath` путь с библиотекой `org.apache.httpclient`.

Answer (score 1):

Так у вас все компилируется, но не работает в райнтайм. `HttpClient` отсутствует в `classpath`.